# PhpStorm resolve dynamic require path in WordPress project

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm

I have my WordPress theme folder path setup like this:

```
define( 'theme_lib', get_template_directory() . '/inc');
```

I am using this in my functions.php:

```
require_once( theme_lib . '/setup.php');
```

PhpStorm does not resolve the actual path and gives warning that path not found.

It works at runtime but how should I get the IDE to recognise the include path?

Comment: IDE cannot evaluate path because it's known during run-time only. Just disable that inspection -- it brings little value for actual coding.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22825